# How can I enable ActiveSync connection from Windows CE mobile device?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, activesync

I have Windows XP on computer and Navigator with Windows CE 6.0. They are connected via USB. 
When I enter usb cabel to the navigator - all ok, they becomes connected. But the navigator has the option "Sleep". When navigator goes to sleep - activeSync connection stops. After sleep connection doesn't establish! The help desk of the navigator tells me that the activeSync connects when usb cable inserted.
Can I manually via program on my navigator (or pc) enable the activeSync connection?

P.S. I've tried RAPI: function ActiveSync.ConnectNow() didn't affect